# config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, c

Привет! Пытаюсь скомпилять [это](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/tests/tcpflood.c) чтоб создать нагрузку на свой rsyslog для тестирования сжатия. Но эта зараза ни в какую не хочет компиляться, ругается на

```
    # make tcpflood
    cc     tcpflood.c   -o tcpflood
    tcpflood.c:86:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
     #include "config.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    <builtin>: recipe for target 'tcpflood' failed
    make: *** [tcpflood] Error 1
```

Пробовал на cetos6 и на debian8. Установка всяких libconfig-dev и т.п. не помогает.

Что ей надо? Я уже всю голову сломал :( Почему они не выложили в бинарном виде эту утилиту, столько времени уже потрачено из-за неё :'(

Comment: Похоже на то, что _где-то_ у Вас должен быть скрипт (типа configure), который Вы должны запустить на своей машине и получить на выходе ```config.h``` с параметрами, заточенными под Вашу систему. Либо это хэдер ядра.

Answer (score 1):

> Version 1.16.0 (RGer/Peter Vrabec), 2007-07-13 - The Friday, 13th
>   Release ;)
>   - build system switched to autotools
>   - ...
>   - subdirectories linux and solaris are no longer part of the distribution   package. This is not because we cease support for them,
>   but there are no   longer any files in them after the move to
>   autotools

Если я правильно понимаю этих ребят - см. первый комментарий.
[Файл](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/configure.ac) лежит в корне проекта.

Comment: Это исходник, чтобы получить скрипт,!надо вначале запустить в правильной последовательности Autotools: типа *autoheader; automake; autoconf; ./configure; make*. Иногда дают *autogen.sh* в комплекте, но его можно и скопировать из дистрибутива. Команды не помню. Но вообще авторы софтины, конечно, "молодцы" с такими исходниками.